# Код не работает!

Tags: java

Привет! 
Изучаю Java совсем недавно. Задача в следующем: человек должен вводить в консоли имя, логин и пароль, после чего программе следует проверить логин на причастность к динамическому массиву и, если его там нет, то добавить его, а если он есть, вывести предупреждение об ошибке.
При запуске открывается окно ввода,куда спокойно вводятся вышеупомянутые "имя", "логин" и "пароль". Однако, программа не производит проверку логина на причастность к массиву и не выводит сообщение об ошибке, как впрочем не выводит и сами поля массива. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name = bReader.readLine();
        String login = bReader.readLine();
        String password = bReader.readLine();
        UserADD(name,login,password);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> UserADD(String name,String login,String password) {
        ArrayList <String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.contains(login)) {
                System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
            }
            else users.add(name);   users.add (login);users.add(password);
        {
            System.out.println(users);
        }

        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

---

Спасибо всем большое, однако проблема осталась. При попытке второго пользователя ввести логин первого, программа спокойно его принимает, игнорируя какие-либо ограничения и предупреждение на экран не выходит. Попробовал все варианты.

Comment: Ну вы каждый раз создаете лист `users` через `ArrayList <String> users = new ArrayList<String>();`. соответственно в цикле не пробегает, потому что размер ноль........плюс еще скобки не так расставлены там где `else`.......а вообще, как по мне, надо бы делать list User. и добавлять именно юзера, с его всеми данными. ну это имхо.

Comment: Потому что список юзеров надо вынести в класс и сделать статическим. Тогда значения будут храниться в глобальной переменной и при каждом вызове метода все будет работать.  Плюс, лучше использовать `Set` для хранения неповторяющихся значений.

Comment: Не информационный заголовок, переформулируйте пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, очень странный участок кода

```
else users.add(name);   users.add (login);users.add(password);
{
    System.out.println(users);
}
```

Похоже, что вы запустались в скобках.

Во-вторых, задача стоит проверять логин на занятость. Не вижу смысла добавлять в список имя и пароль.

В-третьих, вам не нужен перебор списка. Достаточно условия

```
if(users.contains(login)) {
    System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
}
else {
    users.add(login);
}
```

Наконец, вы создаёте пустой список при каждом вызове метода UserADD и никуда его не сохраняете. Когда метод завершается, переменная users выходит из области видимости и сборщик мусора её удаляет.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть что-то наподобие:

```
public class Test {

    private static Set<String> users;
    //Предполагаю, что в списке значения хранятся в формате <Имя, Логин, Пароль>
    public static Set<String> addUser (String name, String login, String password){
        //Если множенство не инициализировано, то самое время.
        if (users==null) users = new HashSet<>();
        //Триггер на дубликат
        boolean b = false;
        //Проходим итератором, т.к. в будущем, если что можно будет без проблем удалить элемент (если, допустим, будет опция замены)
        Iterator<String> iterator = users.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            //Получаем логин (2-й элемент) разбивая строку на кусочки в массив. Разделитель запятая.
            if (iterator.next().split(",")[1].equals(login)){
                b = true;
            }
        }
        //Если все ок, то добавляем
        if (!b) {
            users.add(name+","+login+","+password);
        }else {//Иначе говорим о проблеме и больше ничего не делаем.
            System.out.println("Такой логин("+login+") уже существует");
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```